# Strange line appearing in tikz plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am generating plots using matlab2tikz and then including all of these .tikz files into my dissertation. I have declared the following in the the .tex file

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
```

because many of the plots contain lots of data points and its gets difficult to compile it all at together.

The problem is that many of the plots contain this strange vertical line through them as shown and I have no idea where this is coming from. It occurs in many of the plots and I don't know how to remove it.

If anybody has any ideas I would be very grateful.

I cant post a screenshot of what it is because but its just a slightly gray line that runs down the right hand side of the plot on each figure

[image: With the line]
[image: Without the line]

Comment: I am trying to break it down to a minimal example but now i cant reproduce the problem in the example. I could post two shots of when the line appears happens and when it doesnt. The file size of the PDF file size produced shoots through the roof when it gives the problem if that makes any difference. Document went from being 30MB without any problems to nearly 1GB

Comment: @Gerard Do you have markers with shading or 3D shading? With what are you compiling?

Comment: @percusse I am plotting test data. Just basic x vs y stuff, I have edited the OP to give two shots of when it happens and when it doesn't. This is one of the more simpler plots with not much data, most of my plots are couple 1000 data points each.

Comment: When it happens can you add the option `clip=true` to the axis options as the last one and try again? That means pgfplots will not draw anything outside the axis environment. That would take out some possibilities.

Comment: With no MWE or feedback on percusse's question, this is 'unclear'.